# Monthly or weekly report of PayPal Completed Payments automatically

Tags: csv, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

We can download a CSV or XLS of PayPal Completed Payments by manually going to https://business.paypal.com/merchantdata/reportHome and doing "Activity download":

[image]

**But how to get this CSV report, automatically (via email or with an API), each week or each month, without having to manually log in on the website?**

Note:

- I've already looked at [PayFlow reports](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/reports/payflow-reports/) and [download-reports](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/reports/#download-reports) but it seems quite complex, and there is no full example (only [XML samples](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/reports/payflow-reports/samples/) but it's unclear how to use them)
- I don't want to use IPN for this (I do use it for another task, but it's not perfectly reliable for other reasons, etc.)

Example of desired output:

```
"Date","Time","TimeZone","Name","Type","Status","Currency","Gross","Fee","Net","From Email Address","To Email Address","Transaction ID","Shipping Address","Address Status","Item Title","Item ID","Shipping and Handling Amount","Insurance Amount","Sales Tax","Option 1 Name","Option 1 Value","Option 2 Name","Option 2 Value","Reference Txn ID","Invoice Number","Custom Number","Quantity","Receipt ID","Balance","Address Line 1","Address Line 2/District/Neighborhood","Town/City","State/Province/Region/County/Territory/Prefecture/Republic","Zip/Postal Code","Country","Contact Phone Number","Subject","Note","Country Code","Balance Impact"
"3/1/2018","04:52:07","CET","John Doe","Website Payment","Completed","EUR","100.00","0","100","johndoe@gmail.com","contact@example.com",...
"3/1/2018","16:29:30","CET","Mike Abcd","Website Payment","Completed","EUR","100.00","0","100","mikeabc@example.com","contact@example.com",...
```

Answer (score -2):

You will have to do it through the XML api.  Basically, you make a post request with the example XML in the link you gave but with your data.  The response will be in XML and you take the returned `reportId` and then call the get report api and it will return in xml the report data.

Comment: Can you please provide more details, with an example XML in the answer, for completeness?  (as it stands, it's not really an answer, but rather a comment). `The response will be in XML`: how to have a report like the usual CSV reports we can download on the website? `then call the get report api`: how? the goal of the question was to have details/examples about this. Thanks a lot in advance if you can add these details to the answer.